# Creating multiple accounts in metamask automatically

Tags: metamask, airdrop, account-generation

Say I could travel back in time, and wanted to take advantage of the uniswap airdrop.

Would it be possible to create multiple adresses on my metamask account through the web console of my pc, instead of manually adding them one by one? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Metamask is a wallet meant to be used manually.

If you want to create multiple addresses automatically, the only way I know is to code it using a web3 library such as [web3js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/), or perhaps with a script with the [geth javascript console](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/javascript-console).